# Simple batch for checking internet connectivity and setting environment variable %internet% depending on result

Tags: file, batch-file, ping

I want to check internet connection, when it fails I want to set `%internet%` to not connected. And if it works to `connected`.

```
echo checking internet connection
Ping www.google.nl -n 1 -w 1000
cls
if errorlevel 1 (set internet=Not connected to internet)
if errorlevel 0 (set internet=Connected to internet)
```

I also tried this:

```
@echo off
cls
echo Checking connection
ping -n 1 www.google.com >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
  cls
  set "%internet%"=="Not connected to internet"
  echo %internet%
  pause>nul
  exit
)

cls
set "%internet%"=="Connected to internet"
echo %internet%
pause>nul
pause
```

---------------EDIT------------

This is more of the code.

```
@echo off
set versienummer=v3.1
title AutoMatic Program Install Stable %versienummer% by eric
color 0a
:CheckOS 
IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="x86" (set bit=x86) else (set bit=x64)
set "windows="
VER | find  " 5.1." > nul && set windows=XP
VER | find  " 5.2." > nul && set windows=XP 64-Bit or Server 2003 or Server 2003 R2 
VER | find  " 6.0." > nul && set windows=Vista or server 2008
VER | find  " 6.1." > nul && set windows=Win7 or server 2008 R2
VER | find  " 6.2." > nul && set windows=Windows 8
VER | find  " 6.3." > nul && set windows=Server 2012 R2 or Windows 8.1
if defined windows (
echo %windows%
) else (
echo unknown operating system
)
:ReturnToBaseLine



echo checking internet connection
Ping www.google.nl -n 1 -w 1000
cls
if errorlevel 1 (set internet=Not connected to internet)
if errorlevel 0 (set internet=Connected to internet)
SET Connected=false
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1" %%A IN (`PING google.com`) DO (
REM Check the current line for the indication of a successful connection.
IF /I "%%A"=="Reply" SET Connected=true
)
REM Check if a success was found.
IF "%Connected%"=="true" SET internet=Connected to internet

REM If we get here, we are not connected.
set internet=Not connected to internet
pause

REM Quit.



color 0a
cls
echo Made By The Amazing 
echo.
echo    ____    _       ________         ___                            
echo   / __/___(_)___  /_  __/ /  ___   / _ \_______ ___ ___ _  ___ ____
echo  / _// __/ / __/   / / / _ \/ -_) / // / __/ -_) _ `/  ' \/ -_) __/
echo /___/_/ /_/\__/   /_/ /_//_/\__/ /____/_/  \__/\_,_/_/_/_/\__/_/   
echo.                                                                   
Echo     %bit% processor architecture           versie %versienummer%
echo     %windows%
echo     %internet%
echo.
```

-----------------------------edit 3 ------------------
DONE

Comment: not related to your problem, but this may make you life easier: `for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('wmic os get Caption^, OSArchitecture /value^|find "="') do set %%i`, `echo %Caption%, %OSArchitecture%`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With a tweak, your original code will work.

```dos
echo checking internet connection
Ping www.google.nl -n 1 -w 1000
cls
if errorlevel 1 (set internet=Not connected to internet) else (set internet=Connected to internet)

echo %internet%
```

The issue is that `IF ERRORLEVEL n` is TRUE if `errorlevel` is n **or greater than n**. `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` is therefore always true. `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1` is a test for errorlevel=0. So is `IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0`, except that the former can be used within a block but the latter cannot.

Nence, your code *was* setting `not connected` but the following line, since the `if` condition is always true, overwrites the value with the second message.

Note that `set "%internet%"=="Connected to internet"` means "set a variable, the name of which is stored in the variable `internet` to the value"

Hence, if `internet` had a value of `fred` at that time, then `fred` would be set to the value, not `internet`.

Furthermore, Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Thus, since you are setting `internet` with a block (the `if - true` statement sequence, then you need to use one of the two common ways to overcome this. 1) use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values. A method technically related to the second is to use the statement `call echo %%internet%%` to display the changed value of `internet` within a block.

Comment: when i implemen his in my code the result is echo is off. when i just make a new batch file it does work tho. ill play with it a little see what i can make.

Answer (score 6):

Another option...

```
ping -n 2 -w 700 10.11.1.1 | find "TTL="
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    SET internet=Connected to the internet.
) ELSE (
    SET internet=Not connected to the internet.
)
echo %internet%
```

This works well because...

- Sometimes the return for ping is `Reply from 10.11.1.106: Destination host unreachable.` and since it has an errorlevel of zero this fails. (at least for me)
- `ping -n 2` will still pass if there happens to be a dropped packet.

Comment: Hello. This is not good for me because I don't know the language of the windows computer which will run this batch, and the windows application "ping" is localized (in french on my french computer). So there will be no string matching "bytes". I think that a test on "TTL=" would be better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on using TTL instead.  I updated the answer in case anyone else runs into this.  I just did a quick test and TTL also works.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. The idea is it checks each line of the `PING` result for the line starting with "Reply" (which indicates success) and if it finds it on a single line then it sets the `%Connected%` variable to `true`.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET Connected=false
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1" %%A IN (`PING google.com`) DO (
    REM Check the current line for the indication of a successful connection.
    IF /I "%%A"=="Reply" SET Connected=true
)

REM Check if a success was found.
IF "%Connected%"=="true" (
    SET Internet=Connected to the internet.
) ELSE (
    SET Internet=Not connected to the internet.
)
```

Comment: but if i try to implement it in my code it doesn't work. or am i doing it wrong here ?

Comment: Check your `ping`output. It's language dependent. "Reply" might not be "Reply" with your windows.

Comment: @user2991298 - The way you are using it is a bit off. I updated my answer to use an If-Else structure instead of Goto - which is more in line with what you are doing. Try implementing this instead and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Using ping is not a great idea for testing Internet connectivity.
Several firewall block ping packets. I suggest to use portqry an official MS command line utility.
https://support.microsoft.com/it-it/help/310099/description-of-the-portqry-exe-command-line-utility

Answer (score -1):

NETSH INTERFACE SHOW INTERFACE | FINDSTR "Connected" > NUL && echo yes || echo no

Comment: This code requires formatting. In addition, you need to include an explanation as to how, or why determining whether a network device is connected relates to whether a connection to the internet, (as opposed to intranet) is available. Code only answers are generally frowned upon on StackOverflow.